# How to round, floor, ceil, truncate

Tags: json, math, jq, truncate

How can I round, floor, ceil, and truncate a number in jq jq-1.5-1-a5b5cbe?

For example, with `{"mass": 188.72}`, I want `{"mass": 188}` with floor, `{"mass": 189}` with ceil and round.

Rounding examples:

```
5.52 --> 6
5.50 --> 5 or 6
-5.52 --> -6
```

Truncate examples:

```
5.52 --> 5
5.50 --> 5
-5.52 --> -5
```

I have come up with `-5 as $n | if $n > 0 then [range($n+0.00000000000001)] else [range(-$n)] end | last` for truncate, but it is needlessly complex (and likely contains bugs).

Comment: Whay are you not making use of Math.round, Math.ceil functions?

Comment: @oguzismail jq-1.5-1-a5b5cbe

Comment: @Nitheesh From https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.5/#Math: "Availability of standard math functions depends on the availability of the corresponding math functions in your operating system and C math library". Using round, I get `jq: error: round/0 is not defined at <top-level>, line 1`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Some builds may lack those functions, but as far as I'm concerned `floor` is widely available; so, you can implement them using it.

### round/0

```
def round: . + 0.5 | floor;
```

### ceil/0

```
def ceil: if . | floor == . then . else . + 1.0 | floor end;
```

### trunc/0

```
def trunc: if . < 0 then ceil else floor end;
```

Answer (score 5):

In jq 1.6 you have access to round/ceil/floor functions

```
$ echo '{"mass": 188.72}' | jq ' .mass | round '
189
$ echo '{"mass": 188.72}' | jq ' .mass | ceil '
189
$ echo '{"mass": 188.72}' | jq ' .mass | floor '
188
$
```

For jq 1.5, here is the hack

Round:

```
$ echo '{"mass": 188.42}' | jq ' .mass + 0.5 | tostring | split(".") | .[0] '  -r
188
```

Ceiling(may have to add more 9999s to increase precision):

```
$ echo '{"mass": 188.42}' | jq ' .mass + 0.99999999 | tostring | split(".") | .[0] '  -r
189
```

Floor:

```
$ echo '{"mass": 188.42}' | jq ' .mass | tostring | split(".") | .[0] '  -r
188
```

Comment: Is there solution for jq version less than 1.6?

Answer (score 1):

jq's math builtins are enumerated in the Math section of the jq Manual. The current release is at https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/;
links to earlier versions are at the top.

Note that both jq 1.5 and 1.6 have builtins named `round`, `ceil`, `floor` and `trunc`: they are all 0-arity filters.

E.g.

```
[5.52, 5.50, -5.52 ] | map(trunc)

#=> [5,5,-5]
```

Earlier versions of jq have different sets of Math functions, e.g. jq 1.4 has `floor` but not the other three.

Comment: I get `jq: error: trunc/0 is not defined at <top-level>, line 1`

Comment: If upgrading doesn't help, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56593531/jq-error-round-0-is-not-defined-at-top-level/56593877#56593877